# 2-body Umklapp scattering in graphene

Tags: solid-state-physics, collision, many-body, electronic-band-theory, graphene

It is claimed that the Umklapp scattering is forbidden in two-body collision in graphene due to the crystal symmetry in [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys3667) . I am having a hard time to see why this is the case... why wouldn't it be possible to have two momenta in the honeycomb Brillouin zone to sum up to something that's outside the BZ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because, given the energy spectrum, all physics in graphene occurs at the Dirac points (corners of the Brillouin zone in k-space), so an Umklapp scattering would take an electron from one K valley to another. This would require a momentum transfer of the order of $\hbar K$, which is very large compared to momentum transfer in other scattering processes.